# Reinforcement learning Total number of policies given finite states and actions

Tags: machine-learning, reinforcement-learning

I am new to reinforcement learning. So it might seem a trivial question

Assuming 3 states {x,y,z} and 2 actions {a,b}

Why is the total number of policies/search space 2^3 = 8.

Consider these cases,

```
x - y - z (actions a,b)
x - z - y (actions a,b)
y - x - z (actions a,b)
y - z - x (actions a,b)
z - x - y (actions a,b)
z - y - x (actions a,b)
```

This would only give me 6 policies? Then considering * 2 due to actions (b,a) it will give me 12 policies.

Am i missing something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming a deterministic policy (which is your case), a policy determines the action that should be performed in each state. In your case, you have 3 states `(x,y,z)` and two possible actions `(a,b)`. Then, these are your possible policies:

```
+---+---+---+
| x | y | z |
+---+---+---+
| a | a | a |
| a | a | b |
| a | b | a |
| a | b | b |
| b | a | a |
| b | a | b |
| b | b | a |
| b | b | b |
+---+---+---+
```

I hope now it's more clear why the total number of policies/search space is 2^3 = 8.